# MVC Fileupload real contenttype

Tags: file, model-view-controller, contenttype

I'd like to know how to check the real type of an uploaded file. Say if it's a .exe file but the user's changed its extension to .jpg before uploading.

HttpPostedFileBase still recognizes it as .jpg... It's a worrisome to me.

Thanks.

Comment: MVC what? Are you talking about ASP.NET-MVC? According to Google, the `HttpPostedFileBase` seems to be part of it. Please edit your question tags accordingly. This site is not only about ASP.NET-MVC. There exist a lot of MVC frameworks and you aren't entirely clear which one you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you have the privilege to view file contents on the client side due to browser security policy.  You are going to have to examine the file on the server once it's been uploaded.